# React Native - setState to fetch response (doesn't set and stops code executing)

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set `users: []` within the App component to the response of `fetch`.

When I try to use `this.setState` to change the value of `users:`, my code stops executing and `this.state.users` remains empty.

Not quite sure whats going on, am I using `componentWillMount` incorrectly ? (Someone used it in a tutorial and I'm a little confused on the correct use of lifecycle methods)

I'm new to this React malarky.

Also due to 'Expo' not responding to me shaking my phone like a madman I can't look at the error logs.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      users: [],
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // Not sure if I'm using this ^ correctly
    this._fetchUsers();
  }

  render() {
    const users = this._getUsers();
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Users</Text>
        <View>
          {users}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _fetchUsers() {
     fetch('http://api.example.111.111.11.111.xip.io/users')
     // This ^ is returning json
     .then((response) => {
       console.log(1)
       // This ^ log is visible 
       this.setState({users: response._bodyText});
       // Code stops executing around here
       console.log(2)
       // This ^ log is not visible
     })
   }

  _getUsers() {
    return this.state.users.map((user) => {
        return(<User
                name={user.name}
                email={user.email}
                key={user.id} />);
    })
  }
}

class User extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View className="user">
        <Text className="user-name">{this.props.name}</Text>
        <Text className="user-email">{this.props.email}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});
```

`response._bodyText` returns an array of user objects similar to this:
`[{id:'1', name:'Steve', email:'steve@example.com'},{id:'2', name:'notSteve', email:'notsteve@example.co.uk'.... ect`

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE: currently re-downloading xcode to get app running on simulator, had many problems with using expo app, it was rebuilding the same code even after saved changes, had to keep re-installing app to run changes and even then still had issues. Should have another update in 45 minutes to an hour, thanks for all the answers so far. Feel like I'm learning things 
:D

LATEST UPDATE: Ok so the problem has been solved though not fully understood.

my `response` looks something like this:

```
Response {
13:43:00:   "_bodyInit": "[{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Joe Bloggs\",\"email\":\"joe@example.com\", ........ect]",
13:43:00:   "_bodyText": "[{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Joe Bloggs\",\"email\":\"joe@example.com\", ........ect]
13:43:00:   "headers": Headers {
13:43:00:     "map": Object { ........... ect
```

So using `response._bodyText` was giving me a string of json which explains why it wasn't working as an object.

As suggested by @Srdjan Cosic

`response.json()` gave me:

```
Promise {
13:54:17:   "_40": 0,
13:54:17:   "_55": null,
13:54:17:   "_65": 0,
13:54:17:   "_72": null,
13:54:17: }
```

I've not covered Promises yet so didn't understand this at all.

and `response.data` gave me `undefined`

FINALLY, what did work `this.setState({users: JSON.parse(response._bodyText)})` as partly suggested by @Srdjan Cosic again.

Strangely, `this.setState({users: JSON.parse(response)})` returned the exact same thing but still didn't work :/

**TL;DR** - I've started using `componentDidMount(thanks for the advise everyone)`, my response json is weird so had to use `this.setState({users: JSON.parse(response._bodyText)})` to turn part of the json into objects.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, according to Reacts documentation on `componentWillMount()` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount
it says

> `componentWillMount()` is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before `render()`, therefore calling `setState()` synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we recommend using the `constructor()` instead.
>
> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. For those use cases, use `componentDidMount()` instead.

which basically means that you should try to call your `._fetchUsers()` in your `constructor()` or `componentDidMount()`.

The second thing, I'm not sure what `response._bodyText` is because I cannot find anything about it on the documentation on Fetch but IF the response object is the one that is described in fetch's documentation then you have access to the `.body` attribute. So instead of doing
`this.setState({users: response._bodyText})` why don't you try `this.setState({users: JSON.parse(response.body)})` This will parse the body (assuming it's in the json format that you described) and turn it into a javascript object.

I use axios and if my response returns a json I can usually access it with `response.data` so that might also work for fetch. Otherwise there is also `response.json()` that in turn returns another promise after the response has been turned into json https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Comment: Not the exact answer (see post update for more details) but got me the closest with what I already had.

Going to mark this answer as solved to for convenience, Thanks

Comment: Ok, yeah it was a bit tricky to understand without your error output but I'm glad it got you into the right direction. To answer your problem with `response.json()` is that it is an promise. So you could write like this 
`fetch("an-url.com").then(response => response.json()).then(response => this.setState({users: response})`
Note: You might have to do JSON.parse() there as well. 

Anyway, glad that it got you somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Never use side effects(asynchronous calls like api calls, fetching data or setState) in componentWillMount() as it is before component is first rendered or mounted. An asynchronous call to fetch data will not return before the render happens. Thus put this._fetchUsers() in componentDidMount().

Let me know if it works)

Comment: now looks like this:

    componentDidMount() {
        this._fetchUsers();
    }

Unfortunately this leads to the exact same outcome, but thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @WilliamOsborne oh, you are using fetch. Fetch returns http response not the actual json. So you have to fetch('http://api.example.111.111.11.111.xip.io/users')
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((response) => console.log(response));

////see console.log output in debugger to see what's the reponse and set the data accordingly. Most of the time it is in data like response.data.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast your `response` to `json` before use it

```
 async _fetchUsers() {
   let response = await fetch('http://api.example.111.111.11.111.xip.io/users');
   let responseJson = await response.json();
   return responseJson.movies;
  })
 }

componentWillMount() {
  let users = this._fetchUsers();
  this.setState({ users });
}
```